# Php get website url after https:// or www. or subdomain

Tags: php

I want to get the correct URL with PHP without any error, my links example:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/search/
https://example.com/search/?q=test

https://it.example.com/
https://it.example.com/search/
https://it.example.com/search/?q=test
```

so i want to get all link if is `https://example.com/ show example.com` if is `https://example.com/search/ show example.com/search/` if is `https://it.example.com/search/?q=test show example.com/search/?q=test` etc.. without any error. thanks

Comment: did you check the `parse_url()`?

Comment: [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is your best friend!

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

`$link = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

Have a look over the PHP documents too: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

This will return the HTTP Host without https, and will also get you the request_uri with query strings etc.

`parse_url()` will also give you each element, and then you can build up the string you need:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: No problem, if it's working for you, remember to mark the answer as correct ;)

Comment: can you show me how i add it on my link example:  `href="//it.<?php $link;?>"` like this is not working, if is possible to show me how? thanks again

Comment: You need to `echo` it `...href="//it.<?php echo $link;?>"`